# To whom it may concern

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

### Look It Up

[image]

To whom it may concern.

#### Text Transcription from image:

> whom@may.concern.com 
> Puzzle Design 
> Each title, image, and description is a potential clue, but not all of them have useful information. Critical thinking will be essential for seperating the  relevant clues from irrelivant ones. Some clues are hardly noticable, so there will be hints to accomodate puzzlers who need a nudge in the right direction. Some of those puzzlers might have a tendancy to look up answers or form groups, but it's actually intended to work that way. The solutions are not easily searchable because many chapters contain oblique clues, and even with a group, each chapter offers enough resistence to provide satisfying payoff. Visually, puzzles will have a minimalistic appearence to avoid too many red herrings. 
> What do you think?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> [**Sinatra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_(disambiguation)) is the initial letters of the misspelled words (*seperating*, *irrelivant*, *noticable*, *accomodate*, *tendancy*, *resistence*, *appearence*), in order.

Comment: Awesome! Correct answer with proper explanation...:)